# Pandas create new columns with count

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that looks like:

import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'car_id':[01,02,03,04,05],
               'crash_severinity' :[unknown, possible injury,not injury,possible injury, unknown]})
```

df

## I would like it to look like this

df

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'car_id':[01,02,03,04,05],
               'unknown' :[1,0,0,0,1],
               'possible injury' :[0,1,0,1,0]
               'not injury:[0,0,1,0,0]})
```

## thanking you in advance!!

Comment: `pd.get_dummies(df.crash_severity)`

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df)
```

Output is:

```
    crash_severity_not injured  crash_severity_possible injury  crash_severity_unknown
0                0                            0                           1
1                0                            1                           0
2                1                            0                           0
3                0                            1                           0
4                0                            0                           1
```

Comment: not sure what dummnies is for  but i want to  create   new columns for each type of injury from  crash_severity column

Comment: This is what dummies do. I added the output of the function on your dataframe.

Comment: Thanks Julien. I got it. It is so simple and useful.

Comment: Then please consider upvoting and accepting the answer so others might find it!

Comment: how to do that. still new here